# Jaxb Annox plugin : Is it possible to change annotation in objectFactory class @XmlElementDecl

Tags: jaxb2-maven-plugin, annox

Im getting 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions The element has more than one mapping. Issue after using an episode file to generate the common classes from 2 xsd files. Now I have 2 objectFactory class with mapping for same element . Im thinking to remove the annotation from one of the factory method as nothing else seems working.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue through another XJC plugin as  jaxb2-annotate-plugin didn't have a provision to add or replace annotations in the ObjectFactory class.

I Found any-annotate plugin which does handle this like a charm.

For more details:
https://gitlab.com/virtual-machinist/any-annotate